# How to call switchIfEmpty when the flatMap returns an empty Mono?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

My title sounds confusing so let me explain with some imperative pseudo code for what I'm trying to do

```
Mono<Void> func() {
  Mono<MyThing> myThing = getMyThing();
  if myThing is not empty:
    return doSomething();
  else:
    return doSomethingElse();
}
```

Here's where I'm stuck when I try to do this reactively:

```
Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
  Mono<MyThing> myThing = getMyThing();
  return myThing
    .flatMap(thing -> {
      Mono<Void> somethingMono = doSomething();
      return somethingMono;
    })
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
      Mono<Void> somethingElseMono = doSomethingElse();
      return somethingElseMono;
    });
}
```

This works fine when `myThing` is empty. It skips the `.flatMap()` and executes the `.switchIfEmpty()` statement.

However, when `myThing` is not empty, it executes `.flatMap()` which is what I want. But the flatMap returns a `Mono<Void>` which triggers the subsequent `.switchIfEmpty()` method.

I tried swapping the position of the `.flatMap()` and `.switchIfEmpty()` but that doesn't work either because the `.switchIfEmpty()` returns a `Mono<Void>` whereas the `.flatMap()` expects a `Mono<MyThing>`.

This seems like a common pattern so wondering what's the right way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few ways you could do this. Since you're using `Mono<Void>` as the return type, you could do something like:

```
getMyThing()
        .delayUntil(thing -> doSomething())
        .switchIfEmpty(doSomethingElse().cast(String.class))
        .then()
```

...but that's not the neatest or clearest IMHO. It's a bit more verbose, but I'd be tempted to map to an optional as so:

```
getMyThing().map(Optional::of).defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty())
        .flatMap(thing -> thing.isPresent() ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse())
        .then()
```

If you need to do this often, you might consider a transformation utility method:

```
public static <T> Mono<Optional<T>> optional(Mono<T> mono) {
    return mono.map(Optional::of).defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());
}
```

...which would then enable you to just do `getMyThing().transform(Utils::optional)` rather than do the explicit mapping / default each time.

Comment: The 1st approach doesn't work for me since I need to return that Mono<Void> in the webfilter so it can be subscribed to. I think it breaks the request flow if I don't by just returning a `.then()`.

Comment: The 2nd/3rd approach might work. I was returning a DUMMY_MYTHING to ensure I never have an empty Mono<MyThing>, but I think wrapping it in an optional and checking `.isPresent()` is a cleaner approach. Don't think I need the `.then()` at the end since both `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` returns the appropriate type. I will try this and accept this solution later

Comment: @kane It shouldn't break the flow - `then()` doesn't complete right away, it just replays the complete / error signals from the publisher, ignoring any value that may be emitted. It seems like that's what the current behaviour is doing anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `.flatMap()` first, you can try calling `.switchIfEmpty()` and make it always return `Mono.empty()`.

When myThing is empty, it will trigger the `doSomethingElse()` which then return `Mono.empty()` and `doSomething()` will not be called.

Sample:

```
  Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
      Mono<MyThing> myThing = getMyThing();
      return myThing
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
          Mono<Void> somethingElseMono = doSomethingElse();
          return somethingElseMono.then(Mono.empty());
        })
        .flatMap(thing -> {
          Mono<Void> somethingMono = doSomething();
          return somethingMono;
        });
    }
```